# Difference between full and mini futures contract

Tags: stock-exchanges, price, futures

What is the difference between the following two Brazilian futures contracts:

1. The [Ibovespa Futures Contract](http://www.bmf.com.br/bmfbovespa/pages/contratos2/pdf/IbovespaFutures.pdf)
2. The [Mini Ibovespa Futures Contract](http://www.bmf.com.br/bmfbovespa/pages/contratos2/pdf/IND_futures_mini.pdf)

As far as I can tell, both are priced in Brazilian Real (R$) following the Bovespa Index exactly. I would have guessed the *mini* contract to be cheaper than the *full* contract, or at least different in some way.

How are the Ibovespa and Mini Ibovespa futures contracts different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of these are futures contracts on the Ibovespa Brasil Sao Paulo Stock Exchange Index; the mini being exactly that, a mini version (or portion) of the regular futures contract. The mini counterpart makes trading the index more affordable to individual investors and hence increase liquidity.